# How do you improve the performance of the ChefDK commands on Windows 10?

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

In the past, I've installed the ChefDK on Windows 7 and it ran fairly quickly. Recently, I installed a new version of the ChefDK on Windows 10 Professional 64-bit on a powerful laptop, yet virtually every Chef command I run is incredibly slow. I noticed the Ruby Interpreter is very slow, so there appears to be a problem with how the ruby version included in the latest ChefDK runs on Windows 10.

Configuration:

```
ruby version: ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.9.0
chef-client version: 14.12.3
delivery version: master (9d07501a3b347cc687c902319d23dc32dd5fa621)
berks version: 7.0.8
kitchen version: 1.24.0
inspec version: 3.9.3
```

I've tried installing one version newer of the ChefDK (3.9.0 from the previous version), which didn't work either.  I've also tried the knife rehash command which didn't work either.

How do I run these commands before I grow more gray hair?

For example, on Windows Server 2016, by just running "Measure-Command {chef -v}", I get abysmal results:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 57
Milliseconds      : 697
Ticks             : 576977245
TotalDays         : 0.000667797737268519
TotalHours        : 0.0160271456944444
TotalMinutes      : 0.961628741666667
TotalSeconds      : 57.6977245
TotalMilliseconds : 57697.7245
```

But when I run on my Windows 10 Enterprise laptop, the results are even worse...

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 17
Seconds           : 21
Milliseconds      : 422
Ticks             : 10414222706
TotalDays         : 0.0120534985023148
TotalHours        : 0.289283964055556
TotalMinutes      : 17.3570378433333
TotalSeconds      : 1041.4222706
TotalMilliseconds : 1041422.2706
```

I expect that running these commands should take a matter of seconds, not minutes.

**Update:**

After updating the ChefDK it's still slow and not very fast, but it's important new information:

```
ChefDK version: 4.2.0
Chef Infra Client version: 15.1.36
Chef InSpec version: 4.7.3
Test Kitchen version: 2.2.5
Foodcritic version: 16.1.1
Cookstyle version: 5.0.0
```

```
Measure-Command { C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\knife.bat --version }
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 10
Milliseconds      : 647

Measure-Command { C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin\knife.bat --version }
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 17
Milliseconds      : 480
```

Answer (score 1):

I improved performance using embedded binaries . For example if your chefdk installed on `C:\opscode\chefdk` , use `C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin` instead of `C:\opscode\chefdk\bin(which added to your global path).`
There is difference :

```
Measure-Command { C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\knife.bat --version }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 523
Ticks             : 95230328
TotalDays         : 0.000110220287037037
TotalHours        : 0.00264528688888889
TotalMinutes      : 0.158717213333333
TotalSeconds      : 9.5230328
TotalMilliseconds : 9523.0328
```

```
Measure-Command { C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin\knife.bat --version }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 3
Milliseconds      : 610
Ticks             : 36100192
TotalDays         : 4.17826296296296E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00100278311111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.0601669866666667
TotalSeconds      : 3.6100192
TotalMilliseconds : 3610.0192
```

Comment: Thank you Elnur.  I'll have to give this a shot.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: You're right, that drastically helps.  It went from 3 minutes 1 second to 19 seconds.  Why is yours 9 and mine is 19?

Comment: I think there can be several issues : CPU,SSD,HDD, OS related settings and etc.

Comment: I tried installing a slightly newer version of the ChefDK, which has improved the performance somewhat.  Now chef takes 1 min 45 seconds without using the embedded.  Now I'm trying to see if I can get the startup powershell script to use the embedded versions by default, but it seems the script seems to override the code.  Regarding the actual hardware, it's very powerful 6 cores @ 2.59 GHz, 32 GB RAM, SSD, and of course Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: You can try edit the global Path variable in windows from ```C:\opscode\chefdk\bin``` to ```C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin```

Comment: I tried that, but what I noticed is that the chef startup script (using the chef icon) calls this script:  C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\start-chefdk.ps1 and if you open that script you'll notice that it appends the non-embedded version.  I've tried tweaking it to force it to use the embedded version but it causes the entire script to fail.

Comment: The non-embedded version avoids doing all the version pinning, which bypasses one of the primary features of ChefDK which is that all the gems are tested together and are pinned.  By hitting embedded bins you're ripping off the mattress tag and voiding the warranty.  This is generally bad advice.  Newer versions of ChefDK should have comparable performance between the embedded and non-embedded paths (fixed fairly recently so ChefDK >= 4.6.35 most likely)

Comment: What I have noticed in this version:

chef --version
ChefDK version: 4.2.0
Chef Infra Client version: 15.1.36
Chef InSpec version: 4.7.3
Test Kitchen version: 2.2.5
Foodcritic version: 16.1.1
Cookstyle version: 5.0.0

Is that the opposite is now true.  The embedded version is actually slower than the regular version.

Knife.bat (Regular) - 10 seconds 647 milliseconds
Knife.bat (Embedded) - 17 seconds 480 milliseconds